# how to add a reset state when user deletes text from otp text inputs using React native otp input?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have created an OTP screen using react-native-otp-input as follows:
[image]

when I enter the code the continue button turns pink as code state is set to the value like follows
[image]

but when I try emptying the code inputs the continue button is still pink as the code state is not refreshed

[image]

My code for the otp input view and continue button is as follows:

```
 <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <OTPInputView
                style={{width: '90%', height: 40}}
                pinCount={5}
                codeInputFieldStyle={{
                  width: 30,
                  height: 45,
                  borderWidth: 0,
                  borderBottomWidth: 1,
                  borderBottomColor: '#808080',
                }}
                codeInputHighlightStyle={{
                  borderBottomColor: '#000',
                  color: '#000',
                  borderBottomWidth: 1,
                  borderWidth: 0,
                }}
                codeInputFieldStyle={{
                  color: '#000',
                  borderBottomColor: '#000',
                  borderBottomWidth: 1,
                  borderWidth: 0,
                }}
                onCodeFilled={(code) => {
                  setCode(code);
                }}
              />
            </View>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
          <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            {code == '' ? (
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: '#C0C0C0',
                  width: 250,
                  height: 50,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  borderRadius: 20,
                  marginTop: '10%',
                }}
                disabled={true}>
                <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 18}}>Continue</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ) : otpresponseLoading == true ? (
              <ActivityIndicator
                size="large"
                color="#FE017E"
                style={{marginTop: '10%'}}
              />
            ) : (
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: '#FF1493',
                  width: 250,
                  height: 50,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  borderRadius: 20,
                  marginTop: '10%',
                }}
                onPress={() => onContinueHandlePress()}>
                <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 18}}>Continue</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          </View>
```

Could anyone please let me know how do I handle the backpress in this dependency? and refresh the state of code when user deletes code?

Any lead would be great, do let me know if anything else is required for better understanding
thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the ```code``` value during the deletion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's try :

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView>
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <OTPInputView
            style={{ width: '90%', height: 40 }}
            pinCount={5}
            codeInputFieldStyle={{
              width: 30,
              height: 45,
              borderWidth: 0,
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
              borderBottomColor: '#808080',
            }}
            codeInputHighlightStyle={{
              borderBottomColor: '#000',
              color: '#000',
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
              borderWidth: 0,
            }}
            codeInputFieldStyle={{
              color: '#000',
              borderBottomColor: '#000',
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
              borderWidth: 0,
            }}
            onCodeChanged={(code) => {
              setCode(code);
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        {code.length !== 5 ? (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              backgroundColor: '#C0C0C0',
              width: 250,
              height: 50,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              borderRadius: 20,
              marginTop: '10%',
            }}
            disabled={true}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 18 }}>Continue</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : otpresponseLoading == true ? (
          <ActivityIndicator
            size="large"
            color="#FE017E"
            style={{ marginTop: '10%' }}
          />
        ) : (
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: '#FF1493',
                  width: 250,
                  height: 50,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  borderRadius: 20,
                  marginTop: '10%',
                }}
                onPress={() => onContinueHandlePress()}>
                <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 18 }}>Continue</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
      </View>
```